# Set environments from sh file in jenkins and keep it for the rest of the build

Tags: jenkins

In my pipeline, I would like to source a file, setting environment variables like `. ./file.sh` and keep them set for the rest of the pipeline.
I think this is not implemented given there's an issue opened for some years already https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10773

At the moment, I tested doing:

```
stage("Stage") {
    steps {
        sh ". ./file.sh && env"
        sh "env"
    }
}
```

The 2 env output different values. I expect Jenkins to create a new shell every time. Is there an option to not invoke a new shell?.

With what I know, I see 3 possibilities:

1. Execute all my commands in one `sh` statement or wrap the execution in a script. The problem is that it makes debugging quite hard.
2. Source the file at each sh command.
3. Create a custom groovy function wrapping the call.

The 2 last solutions sound dirty, any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we can follow `environment` directive feature to handle both global variable and also stage specific variables.

So in your instance if you define all variables from `file.sh` within Global scope, then printing will give desired result.

`pipeline {
    agent any
    environment { 
        myGlobVar = '2020'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            environment { 
                myStgeSpecificVar = 2020.2 
            }
            steps {
                sh 'printenv'
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: This is not what I want to do. The script I use, from a library is doing a bunch of things and setting variables. Your suggestion only involves the environment directive setting only one variable

Comment: As there is no feature built like 'pre-build' stage options, I think it goes via separation of duties - where you can put bunch of things doing some script specific logic in a shell script & execute it with either scripted pipeline syntax or with `sh`. And have all variables defined ( needed by this Jenkins job ) at Global section ( multiple ones in separate lines ). Or within your script business logic you need to `source` that profile file - by separating `name=value` pairs to a new file